# Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String error while updating stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-cloudformation, devops

I am getting ROLLBACK_COMPLETE while try to updating a stack using the following code. Under events, I am not getting an error as "Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String".please help me to find a solution.

Mycode for first stack:

```
Resources:
  myvpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        EnableDnsSupport: true
        EnableDnsHostnames: true
        InstanceTenancy: default
        Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: myvpc

 myinternetgateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
        Tags: 
            - Key: Name
              Value: mygtwy

 mygatewayattach:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref myinternetgateway
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc

 mysubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

 Routetable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc

 Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: myinternetgateway
    Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId: !Ref myinternetgateway
        RouteTableId: !Ref Routetable

 SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref Routetable
        SubnetId: !Ref mysubnet1
```

On update, I added the following. During this time I am getting the error I mentioned earlier

```
 Myec2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
        SecurityGroupIds:
            - !Ref Mysecgroup
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        ImageId: ami-0922553b7b0369273
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        SubnetId: !Ref mysubnet1

 Mysecgroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
        GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc
        SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: '22'
              ToPort: '22'
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When you specify an AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup type as an argument to the
>   Ref function, AWS CloudFormation returns the security group name or
>   the security group ID (for EC2-VPC security groups that are not in a
>   default VPC).

Your template is referencing the security group name where you should be referencing the group ID.

```
Myec2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
        SecurityGroupIds:
            - !GetAtt "Mysecgroup.GroupId"
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        ImageId: ami-0922553b7b0369273
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        SubnetId: !Ref mysubnet1

 Mysecgroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
        GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc
        SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: '22'
              ToPort: '22'
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: @George..thanx dude...iam really playing around with this whole day.thanks for the solution.I have one doubt..cloud formation will return security group id only for default vpc..right? otherwise we have to use !GetAtt to get the id.right?

Comment: If you are creating assets in a VPC the the `GetAtt` is fine; if you are using AWS classic then you have to switch to `Ref`. Bottom line is that your template is creating a VPC so you are safe to use the `GetAtt`

Answer (score 1):

Referencing Security Group by name (instead of `SecurityGroupIds`) works for me:

```
EC2SG1IKTA:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
EC2I1K240:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref EC2SG1IKTA
```